# windows 11 console application icon not showing

Tags: .net, windows, console-application

I'm currently transitioning several .NET and .NET Core console applications from Windows 10 to Windows 11. These applications, developed in .NET 4.8 and .NET Core 3.1, have assigned project icons. When running on Windows 10, the icons display as expected upon application execution. However, the problem arises when these applications are deployed and run in a Windows 11 environment: the icons do not appear at all. This absence of icons is causing challenges for users who need to identify and restart these applications. Could anyone provide insights or solutions to address this issue?

edit:

[image]

[image]

I've included two pictures to show what I mean. When these were on a windows 10 env they were showing the image that I had set to be the icon in the solution. They're now just showing the default icon for a console app.

Edit:
[image]
Picture showing manifest of where ICO file is added.

Comment: Can you show us where how/do you specify your custom icon

Comment: @Q.Rey I've edited the post to show a screenshot of the manifest where the image is declared.

Comment: How do you launch the application?

Comment: @CodeCaster Some of them are onclick deployment so they are launched by clicking setup others are just launched by clicking the exe file within the published folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's an issue of Windows Terminal (rather than Windows 11), which is being [actively tracked on Github](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/14372) (there's also a more comprehensive issue [here](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/4768#issuecomment-1527800607)).

You experience this problem on Windows 11 because Windows Terminal is the default terminal application, but you can change it in:

`Privacy & Security > For Developers > Terminal > Windows Console Host`:

[image]

Comment: This worked thank you for taking the time to answer :)